# JavaScript get this month's 1st date

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get this month's first date. When I use this code in online compiler, I get the expected date like 2023-02-01. When I use it in my code and see this output in console, it shows the date as 2023-01-31.

I don't know why it is working fine in online compiler, but causing problem in console.log. I want to know the reason for this

This is the code I used:

```
let date = new Date();
let first_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Below, I have attached output data for both online compiler and console.log:

[image: This is online compiler output]

[image: console output]

Comment: `toISOString()` always shows the date in UTC

Comment: You probably want `toDateString()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString